# How to maintain the customer's active quote after Magento 2 database migration?

Tags: magento-2.1.3, redis, enterprise-1.14

As per our client requirement, after our Magento1 to Magento2 data migration they expecting that all the active quote customers should not loose their cart items when they back.

To be more clear, A user added a product few weeks ago in Magento1 cart. Now we have migrated to Magento2 with all the Magento1 quote and order data.
Now the user trying to see his cart again, he should see his cart with all the items he added, with Magento2.

We are using `Redis cache and sessions`.

We have tried to use the same `sid` session values.

My question here is, Whether we have a possibility to maintain the same Magento1 sessions in Magento2 as well? and how to persist the cart between magento1 and magento2?